# Junit Testing in Eclipse throws an Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am using Eclipse 3.5 on Unix machine. I am trying to execute a simple (dummy) JUnit. I am using JUnit 4 framework for writting Junit Test Case.

Also, I have added Junit 4.10.jar to the project Build path

Here is my Java Class File:
FileStats.java

```
    package entity;
    public class FileStats {
            public int getAllStats(){
                return 1;
            }
    }
```

FileStatsTest.java

```
    package entity;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import org.junit.Test;
    public class FileStatsTest  {
        @Test
        public void testGetAllStats() {
            assertEquals("its equal",1,new FileStats().getAllStats());
        }
    }
```

On executing the test case I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    Could not find the main class: org.ecli        pse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.  Program will exit.
```

I have searched and tried restarting , cleaning build path etc. But could not get it working. Any suggestions what might be missing would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a corrupted installation. Try using a fresh installation of Eclipse, or reinstalling the junit plugin (not the junit jar).